# Set argparse argument as default switch

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

My `test.py` file has these instructions:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p", "--parameter", default="latest")
parser.add_argument("-q", "--query")
```

I want to make possible to run the script without explicitly setting the switch for "query" argument ("-q" or "--query"), i.e. if I call:

```
python test.py something
```

"something" to be automatically assigned as query argument.

Is that possible?

Comment: You'd have to do so manually; accept both `--query` and a positional argument (both optional) and use one of the two.

Comment: Ok, thanks for confirmation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
import argparse 

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-p", "--parameter", default="latest")
parser.add_argument("-q", "--query")
parser.add_argument("query_string",nargs='?', default=False)

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.parameter: 
   print("zoinks a parameter! %s" %args.parameter)
if args.query or args.query_string: 
   print("making a query %s" % (args.query or args.query_string))
```

Comment: How about adding `dest='query_string'` to the `-q` argument?

Comment: You can't unfortunately. Argparse is pretty opinionated.

Comment: You can set the `dest`, but the results are unpredictable.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

With a `dest` value, the optional argument can set the same attribute as the positional:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-q", "--query", dest='query_string')
parser.add_argument("query_string", nargs='?', default='default')
args = parser.parse_args()

print parser.parse_args('other'.split())
# Namespace(query_string='other')    # the positional value

print parser.parse_args('-q other'.split())
# Namespace(query_string='default')   # the positional default

print parser.parse_args('more -q other'.split())
# Namespace(query_string='other')    # the optional's value
```

You can use the same `dest` for multiple arguments. But nuances on how '?' positionals are handled produce seemingly unpredictable results.

In the `'-q other'` case, the namespace value is first set to 'other', but then it is overwritten by the positional default when the positional is 'parsed' at the end.

In the `'more -q other'` example, the positional value 'more' is set, and then overwritten by the '-q' value.